# Is there a way to have Firefox automatically save images in My Pictures rather than Downloads?

Tags: firefox

What I like about pretty much all versions of Internet Explorer is that it knows to save images in your Mt Pictures folder all other file types in Downloads.  I'd like Firefox to behave the same way as, right now, it saves every download in Downloads.  Is there a way to configure Firefox to do this?

Answer (score 0):

- Use [Dropit (OPENSOURCE)](http://dropit.sourceforge.net/) it keep monitoring your documents and move the extensions you wish to have moved